# Elm: Parent update Child component via ports

Tags: elm

Is it possible for a parent component to pass the result of it's incoming port, to a child component.

I've been looking at this example of composing Parent/Child components (https://www.elm-tutorial.org/en/02-elm-arch/06-composing.html). This is example is great - but I want like to also update the child's model via Ports. Is this possible?

[Example Gist](https://gist.github.com/chrisbuttery/44e3ad81f9d195d0cd557da7a45a0683).

index.js

```
var num = 0;
setInterval(function () {
  num = num + 1
  app.ports.tick.send(num)
},1000);
```

Ports.elm

```
port module Ports exposing (..)

port tick : (Int -> msg) -> Sub msg
```

Main.elm (Parent)

```
import Widget

type Msg
    = WidgetMsg Widget.Msg


update : Msg -> AppModel -> ( AppModel, Cmd Msg )
update message model =
    case message of
        WidgetMsg subMsg ->
            let
                ( updatedWidgetModel, widgetCmd ) =
                    Widget.update subMsg model.widgetModel
            in
                ( { model | widgetModel = updatedWidgetModel }, Cmd.map WidgetMsg widgetCmd )


subscriptions : AppModel -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model =
    Ports.tick WidgetMsg
```

Widget.elm (Child)

```
initialModel : Model
initialModel =
    { count = 0
    , tickValue = 0
    }


type Msg
    = Increase
    | Tick Int


update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update message model =
    case message of
        Increase ->
            ( { model | count = model.count + 1 }, Cmd.none )

        Tick val ->
            ({model | tickValue = val}, Cmd.none)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to specify which child Msg receives the int value from the port. If you update your parent subscriptions function to this, it will send the Widget Tick message:

```elm
Ports.tick (WidgetMsg << Widget.Tick)
```

Comment: So would Widget.elm have to expose this `Tick` Msg type somehow?

I get the following error:

`Cannot find variable 'Widget.Msg.Tick'
66|     Ports.tick (WidgetMsg << Widget.Msg.Tick)
                                   ^^^^^^^^
The qualifier 'Widget.Msg' is not in scope.`

Comment: Oops, it's just `Widget.Tick`. I've updated my answer

Comment: Thanks so much. This solved my problem. I didn't know I had access to Widget.Tick directly